# Access website by using cookie from httpwebrequest windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I no experience in cookie and I trying to use cookie (that I get from `httpwebrequest` **POST** method) to access a website. In the **POST** method, I done the authentication part and finally I get the cookies. I don know how to use this cookie access a website and it similar to this [HttpWebRequest POST Method](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_277791&feature=iv&src_vid=7Wzel-g1U54&v=UV5_b5oaUQk) .

Hope anyone can give me some advise, pointer or some example code. Thank you for help.

Here is my code so far I done.

```
private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the operation
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf =
               IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies",
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
                    {
                        foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(cookieValue.ToString());
                        }
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Close the stream object
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();
            response.Close();

            //allDone.Set();
        }
```

cookie store in TextBox

```
private void ReadFromIsolatedStorage()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs =
               isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
                {
                    tbTesting.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the CookieContainer Class inside the HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the CookieContainer class for getting and setting the cookies. When you use that, it handles everything for you. You don't have to manually set the cookies explicitly. Check the below code.

First create an instance of the CookieContainer class.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Then use it for authentication and then assign it to each request you use for authentication

```
//Login request to get the cookie
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com/login.svc");
req.Method = "POST";
if (req.SupportsCookieContainer)
   req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
.. rest of your code..

//Any other request which needs a cookie
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com/getuserdata.svc");
req.Method = "POST";
if (req.SupportsCookieContainer)
   req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
.. rest of your code..
```

Comment: Thx @nkchandra. I already done the login authentication part and i get the session cookie, and how i use this session cookie to get access to the web page?

Comment: Its better if you use the same process I followed. Otherwise, you can use the `req.CookieContainer.SetCookie()` method

Comment: The second post method can make the webbrowser display the page after login?